# Neo4J 2.0.1 doesn't work with Gephi 0.8.2 and "Neo4J Graph Database Support" plugin

Tags: neo4j, gephi

Have the following versions of software:

Neo4J community: 2.0.1

Gephi: 0.8.2-beta

Neo4J Graph Database Support plugin: for Gephi 0.8.2

I'm using the default.graphdb that came with Neo4j 2.0.1 (started playing with Neo4j yesterday)

While doing full import from Gephi using Neo4J plugin I get this error:

```
Caused by: 
 org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException:
 Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version.
 To enable automatic upgrade, please set  
 configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
```

Now, I found neo4j.properties and uncommented the "allow_store_upgrade=true" part, but nothing has changed. I still get the same error. I'm not even sure that it tries to load that neo4j.properties file, because if I rename the file I still get exact error (I'm 100% sure the path is correct).

Comment: Make sure the plugin you want to use is really for Neo4j 2.0.1 the old one around was still for Neo4j 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Edit your neo4j.properties file, uncomment the following line :

allow_store_upgrade=true

This will automatically upgrade your database to support the newer neo4j version

Comment: "This will automatically upgrade your database to support the newer neo4j version"
And probably will make it unreadable from the software which created the database in the first place :-)