# Using visualization tools similar to neo4j web interface in my own nodejs app

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graph-visualization

I am developing a simple web app to help visualize the relationship between different terms.
neo4j is a great tool for managing the database but I need some tools to help me visualize the relationships for the users.
I looked at popular choices like sigmajs and three.js. However, they are not good at showing the types of relationships.
I realized that the web interface provided by neo4j itself is a good tool for visualization except for the small font size. But I don't know any way to use it in my own app(looks like it uses SVG which is okay for me).
Any good suggestions on good tools for visualizing the relationships or ways to "grab" the neo4j web interface for my own project?

Comment: just a note for other who might have missed it: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your man is [Max de Marzi](https://twitter.com/maxdemarzi), he's the one working on visualizing neo4j data. In his tutorials he used [vivagraph.js](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS), [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) ...

Check out his website http://maxdemarzi.com/ and his github's https://github.com/maxdemarzi.

You could also have a look at the question [Big data visualization using "search, show context, and expand on demand" concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893401/interactive-and-dynamic-graph-visualization).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I looked at his tutorials before but it looks like a lot of concepts with no technical details. For now I think the tree layout from d3.js best suits me. Any other good resources to get started on it except for the d3.js API?