# Neo4j Graph database representation library

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I will get Neo4j JSON data from AJAX call and I need to render the data. Is there any JS library where I can use the data as input and it will generate SVG output?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893401/interactive-and-dynamic-graph-visualization/21907330#21907330 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several.   [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is a very commonly used framework for this purpose, and so is [Vis.js](http://visjs.org/).  A third option is [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/).   There are probably a dozen more, if you look.

All of them will have one common issue: they won't take JSON in the format delivered by the Neo4J RESTful services, so you'll have to write your own glue code to transform the data from Neo4J's format into whatever format the library you're using requires.

Comment: Is there any D3.js tutorial where I can change the display style?

Comment: have a look at their gallery of display types on the website.   How to change the style depends in part on the display type (force directed, chord, etc)