# Directed, acyclic graph in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there a reliable way of drawing directed, acyclic graphs in D3.js today? I'm trying to visualize prerequisites in a curriculum, [similar to this](http://einstein.franklin.edu/itec/ITEC_Prerequisites_2011.png).

I've seen some older answers to similar questions with the most promising lead being [this hack](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500), though it doesn't work reliably well with larger and more complex data sets.

Is this simply a rare case of a visualization that D3 is not ideal for?

Comment: There's no layout in D3 to achieve this if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may have a try to [dagre](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre), a JS library for DAG graphs.

If you want to use d3 for whatever reason, have a look at [dagre-d3](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3)

For a more high-level approach have a look [at this project](https://github.com/nickholub/d3-dag-visualization) using all the libs above.

If `d3` is not mandatory have also a look [at others graphs library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893401/interactive-and-dynamic-graph-visualization/21907330#21907330). ;)

**Update for September 2018**

There is a new library , called [d3-dag](https://github.com/erikbrinkman/d3-dag)

Comment: I haven seen dagre, but D3 is being used elsewhere in the project and I very much enjoy the power it brings, so I'm trying to avoid adding yet another visualization library unless absolutely necessary. The fact that dagre-d3 is larger than the complete d3 library also doesn't make me super happy.

Comment: I see. `dagre-d3` includes also `lo-dash` so maybe that's the reason of the size. `dagre` itself works as layout module and you could find your way to use it with `d3` - it is the best open source hierarchical/dag layout out there IMHO.

Comment: @MarcoL dagre seems to be abandoned `This project is not being actively developed or maintained.`  Dagre is also build with d3 v3.  Is there a d3 v4 alternative arouns?

Comment: I've updated the answer. TBH I think it is still worth using dagre-d3 forking it and using the newer version of d3.

Comment: @Tucker/everyone - [dagre](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre) is up and running again, and now supports d3 v4/v5

Comment: dagre is a good suggestion for you guys.

Answer (score 5):

Way late but perhaps relevant to others searching for similar information...

[Elkjs](https://github.com/OpenKieler/elkjs) supports layered graph layout and appears to still be actively maintained at this time.

Some suggested layout options based on the OP's usecase...

```
layoutOptions: {
        'org.eclipse.elk.algorithm': 'layered',
        'org.eclipse.elk.direction' : 'DOWN',
        'org.eclipse.elk.edgeRouting': 'SPLINES',
        'org.eclipse.elk.layered.edgeRouting.sloppySplineRouting': false,
        'org.eclipse.elk.layered.layering.strategy': 'INTERACTIVE' }
```

These options can be pasted into [this interactive editor](https://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/elklive/json.html) to see how the layout is affected.

Comment: Big problem of elkjs is that it is using sprotty instead of d3 and there is no simple example of "copy-paste this to try it in your environment". But I used predecessor of elkjs - klayjs and it is working fine. It has simple example and it has klayjs-d3 bridge.

Comment: elkjs uses neither sprotty nor D3. It's just a layout library. You have you take care of the rendering yourself by choosing a rending library (e.g. sprotty, D3, etc.)

Comment: I'll add that elkjs is probably one of the best workflow-esque layout engines.

Comment: I built a project on elkjs for react - https://reaflow.io that you might find interesting.