# Vertical graph with multiple parents for some nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-theory

I am trying to create a vertical graph with d3.js which can have multiple parents for the child nodes. Something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8326869 but with the 'Level2: B' node also linking to 'Daughter of A'. I have also tried searching for other Javascript libraries which could do this but I haven't managed to find anything that works. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Maybe answers to this question can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636643/directed-acyclic-graph-in-d3-js