# What tool should I use for implementing OrientDB on web app?

Tags: database, web-applications, data-visualization, orientdb

I'm learning OrientDB and trying to write a web app to show data in graph. I'm confused about the data visualization tools.

So, **I need to visualize data on web, for example, a user can query some data and get a graph.**

I know that the OrientDB already provided a graph interface for data management (the one with port 2480). But I'm not sure whether this can be implemented in a web app. Or I need to use tools like D3.js and Alchemy.js.

Comment: You can interact with an orientdb database using its drivers : https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Programming-Language-Bindings.html

Comment: @AlexB Is that only to interact with the database? Can one one of them return a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB is written 100% in Java. You can use the native [Java APIs](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Java-API.html) without any driver or adapter.

The graph api combined with Tinkerpop will give you a complete stack of tools to handle graphs. Check out the [graph api](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html) documentation for more information.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893401/interactive-and-dynamic-graph-visualization) tells you how to visualize a graph database. It also gives you a list of generic visualisation tools available.

Like discussed in the post, you need to follow these steps :

1. create layer on top of your source to let you query at high level
2. create a front end layer to talk with the level explained above
3. use the visualization tool you want

Comment: Thanks, so is this mean that I have to use a third party tool?

Comment: Yes you have to use another visualisation tool. The orientdb graph editor is not available.

Comment: Speaking of visualization tools, you can export your graph to GraphML and then visualize it with Gephi (https://gephi.github.io/).